# MS Access Report not recognizing a field that shouldn't be relevant?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

As a bit of a preface here, I use Access at work, I'm mostly self-taught and I know very little code (if I look at the code, can usually figure out what it does, sometimes I can mimic it).

I've built a crosstab query for handling a summary of all material types since 2009. I had to do some fiddling to get it to sort by month and year, but after finally getting that working, any report I run now pops the error:

"The Microsoft Access Database Engine does not recognize '[Pit Tickets].[Ticket #]' as a valid field name or expression."

Now, I've done some research on this and could only find examples where this error crops up because someone actually USED the field. In this case, the [Ticket #] field isn't even referenced in my query, so I'm not sure why a report based off that query would be giving me an error about it.

Query Code:

```
TRANSFORM Sum([PitTickets].Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity
SELECT Year([Date]) AS [Year], Month([Date]) AS [Month No], [Pit Tickets].[Ticket Type], Format$([Pit Tickets].[Date],'mmmm yyyy') AS [Date], Sum([Pit Tickets].Quantity) AS [Total of Quantity]
FROM [Pit Tickets]
GROUP BY Year([Date]), Month([Date]), [Pit Tickets].[Ticket Type], Format$([Pit Tickets].[Date],'mmmm yyyy')
ORDER BY Year([Date]), Month([Date])
PIVOT [Pit Tickets].Material;
```

I have been scratching my head about this since yesterday, can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the property sheet for the query to see if there was an Order By or Filter added at some stage. You could also cut and paste the SQL into a new query window and check if you get the same problem.

[image: property sheet]

Comment: Thanks, I did that actually. And reworked the report testing different group options.

Comment: Does the query work without problems? Does a newly created report based on the query work without problems?

Comment: The query works without problems. Any report based off that query gives me the error.

Comment: Is the crosstab based on a query with a WHERE statement? If so, you will need to add a parameter.

Comment: It's not...it's based on the table.

Comment: Have you gone through the corruption steps? Back-up, compact & repair, decompile?

Comment: I did not...I don't know how to do that; I have, however, fixed the problem by renaming the 'Ticket #' field to 'Ticket No' in my table. No idea why that worked or why it wasn't a problem til now...but as long as it's working I'm happy. Thanks for your help!